# Is there a way to define the type based on the valued on a nested key?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have an api that will give back two different shapes of response based on the user type. I have different routes based for each of those types. Inside those routes I will need to access to those information so I'm saving all of this in the React Context.

As the title implies, I would like to know if there is a way to handle this situation so that I **can** access to the right informations inside my routes?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
type ClientRole = {
  id: UserTypes.user;
  name: string;
};

type ProfessionistRole = {
  id: UserTypes.professionist;
  name: string;
};

type Client = {
  role: ClientRole;
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  display_name: string;
  email: string;
  related: RelatedUser[];
  age: number;
  city: string;
  subscriptions: any[];
};

type Professionist = {
  role: ProfessionistRole;
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  display_name: string;
  email: string;
  related: RelatedUser[];
  badges: any[];
  tags: Tags[];
  experiences: string[];
  method: string;
  description: string;
  age: number;
  city: string;
  account: Account;
  plans: Plans[];
};

type UserProfile = Client | Professionist;
```

for what I know nested properties cannot are not enough for the compiler to infer the correct type; having the discriminant information right on the upper level would have made this easier. Does anyone have some suggestion on what I can try to do?

Comment: Yes, a kind/type field for Client and Professionist seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```ts
const isClient = (userProfile: UserProfile): userProfile is Client => {
   return userProfile.role.id === UserTypes.user;
}
```

```
const userProfile: UserProfile = ...;

if (isClient(userProfile)) {
   // userProfile now have type Client
} else {
   // userProfile now have type Professionist
}
```

See it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgFQJ4AdhygbwFBSFRgKIA0BR6iA9gGZZwCWNITcALngL554cZgUAMIAbJqA4AlGqKEBeXJSYATAFyxSaTHAB0JJAG5KIAIYRgGzoiYgA5se7H+gqAAVaDOM1btpshSVCVQ14JG0sXWp6RhY2TmNCMwsrDht7R2cBTBFxSShFfEJaOQ0xCRB-OUSoEKhrWwdKOiZETgB9ZMt6tMaa0VMOrtT0psIVdnQB1E7zboaMymAIUyZREb7KUztu8AgAIyNKAGMmAQ3Fwjgwfbhjm3QOOLgNUxBUAG0AXUy+bKEPDFvHE-AUglASt1AV4fPEqsAanUFmMoC02hxZikeqN+oMMcNsZtxpNppj5r1LlBlqt1oTKftTCodi8oG9Pj8lgAPTA2UDHLAXOzfGoWDgACxo6jpKJUWHuTEecUFNW2u0gh0QNVO52lvz+rjCiGha0C5XyAB93J5Yr4EnxjqxOLU4GbKmCABQGI2eE2hUjGuQASg0XoDQnYuQqHAKAD5wRDgBwwIgQMR-T65LpIbpVAV5IpDRE9F7HHxZccBoghA6QE7Qxnuoaw84mHQoO72K6OJ70-QTYHA-G00gw1AAPRj4fevtyKAgGgAdygYtMADchP9I5IeFTRAgh-WZ0IJ1PR-Olyv11BN9CbXCeEA).